# A question about different intensity of a sound source in a room

Tags: acoustics

A few days ago, I entered a temple room with dimensions (which are only approximate) shown below in the diagram. There was a low humming sound of the exhaust fan which was at a height of approximately 6 feet from the ground in one corner of the room. Interestingly, the intensity of the sound remained more or less the same throughout the room but increased rapidly as I moved towards the diagonally opposite corner of the room (marked as A in the diagram). Also, the sound was intense only at the height of the exhaust fan and decreased vertically downwards to the level which it was throughout the room. The ceiling of the room was not flat but dome shaped extending from a height of 6 feet to approximately 9 feet. I could not understand exactly the reason as to why only in the diagonally opposite corner of the room the intensity of the sound increased. I feel that the dome shaped ceiling has to be the reason behind it. Can anyone help understand what exactly happens to the sound waves in the room?

[image]

Comment: You could [simulate](http://i-simpa.ifsttar.fr/) it...

Answer (score 3):

This is related to so called [room modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_modes). These are caused by [standing waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave) forming between two walls or between the floor and ceiling. With a room that you described the frequencies where these waves form should be somewhere around 50-100Hz.

What this means in practice is that when standing in a position where such a wave forms, there is a strong boost to a room mode frequency. In your case it happens to be that the noise from the exhaust contains these room frequencies and the phenomenon can be clearly heard.